# Is there a way to find out why MySQL crashed or quit working?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have MySQL running on an Ubuntu 12.04 web server.  A basic LAMP stack.

I just have a couple of small websites running.

- a WordPress site
- A SugarCRM app
- little apps here and there.  Only 2 domains though

Today I made a new post on WordPress and checked back 30 minutes later to see an error...

**Error establishing a database connection**

I then checked my 2nd domain which has SugarCRM and saw an error there as well in regards to connecting to the database.

I then SSH'd into the server and ran `service mysql restart`

Checked my sites again and all was well!

So my question is, is there a way to find out what could of cause this to happen in some sort of log?  Or any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. MySQL has magical logs. For example:

- The Error Log
- The General Query Log
- The Update Log
- The Binary Log
- The Slow Query Log
- Server Log Maintenance

You'll need to check your `my.cnf` to see which logs are enabled and where they are located. You'll also need to check your version of MySQL to find out what configuration options exist for each log, and how to enable it if it's not already.

Once you do, you're just a `less`, `grep`, and maybe a `sed` or two away from finding what took your server down.

Comment: Thanks, i've been a PHP developer for around 14 years but only the past year or 2 have really dug into the server admin side of the job...it's always fun learning more about the power in linux and it;s tools.  I know `grep` is for searching and `sed` is for manipulating text in files...I am not familair with `less` though so will have to check that out too.  I am really interested in how you can write a bash script and have it install and configure all your software using these tools.  My goal is to eventually write the perfect script to run a single command and have a full LAMP server........

Comment: ...installed and configured just how I want it so that I can run the script on client sites and have a wordpress or magento or even sugarcrm environment up and running in minutes along with email, ftp, etc for a client.  I know I am off topic of my question, just making comment I guess on my end goals.  thanks for the help

Comment: @jasondavis You probably won't want to be writing a shell script for this kind of thing. That's last millennium, and prone to breaking very quickly with any change in OS and package versions. You'll want to look into something like Chef or Puppet, and since you have a focus on coding, you'll fit right in to that kind of thing. TL;DR Don't make bash build scripts, use config management like Chef or Puppet.